# $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{p}\right)=\{a+b\sqrt{p}\mid a, b \in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is a subfield of the field $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Prove that $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{p}\right)=\{a+b\sqrt{p}\mid a, b \in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is a subfield of the field $\mathbb{R}$, where $p$ is a prime number

I know this is true for many primes that I've tried but I don't know how to show this is true generally for all primes.

From the comments I gather this is how to show.

Proof:

1) $0+0\sqrt{p}\in\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{p}})$

2) $a+b\sqrt{p}+ c+d\sqrt{p}=a+c+(b+d)\sqrt{p}\in\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{p}}$

3) $(a+b\sqrt{p})(c+d\sqrt{p})=ac+(ad+bc)\sqrt{p}+bdp\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$

4) $-(a+b\sqrt{p})=-a+(-b)\sqrt{p}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$

5) $(a+b\sqrt{p})^{-1}=(a/a^2-pb^2)+(-b/a^2-pb^2)\sqrt{p}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$)

Verified that this is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, now my question is where does $p$ is a prime come into play?

Comment: Can you write out (or sketch) your proof for, say, $p=2$?

Comment: You need to show that sums and products of such numbers also have that form, and that the reciprocal of such a number $\neq 0$ is also of that form. How far do you get with each point?

Comment: Or can you at least indicate the steps that need to be shown? Given a subset of a field, what properties do you need to show in order to prove that it is a subfield?

Comment: You know this is true for *many* primes that you've tried? Assuming $17$ is among these primes, how dis you verify the claim? And what happens if you replace $17$ by $p$ in that verification?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, does p have to be prime? And why? Thanks

Comment: If $p$ is not prime than, if there is the root you are in the rational numbers. Otherwise, you can factorize your number in a factor of prime numbers. Example: $\sqrt{26} = \sqrt{2.13} = \sqrt{2}.{\sqrt{13}}$. So, what do you do?

Answer (score 1):

Lets try.
For the subfield test we have to check that given $a, b \in S$ a subset of one field $F$ then holds that:
$$a - b \in S$$
$$ ab^{-1} \in S.$$
By one simple calculation this statement holds.
Of course, it is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the subfield test should also verify that $|S|>1$ or $\exists x\ne 0\colon x\in S$.

Comment: Exactly. Is just a simple calculation.

Comment: I tried following your hint with $a=1$ and $b=0$ and my paper caught on fire.  Also all the clocks in my house started spinning.

Comment: ahahaha what do you mean?

Comment: Of course $b$ is not zero. The element $b^{-1}$ is neither defined for $b=0$. You know that.